# Calculating sum of odd numbers between two user inputs

Tags: java, sum, numbers

I am trying to calculate the sum of the odd numbers between two user inputted numbers.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("#1: ");
        int num1 = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("#2: ");
        int num2 = s.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i += 2) {
            sum = sum + i;
        }

        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

When I input 3 and 11, it outputs 35, which is correct.

However, with 4 and 20, it outputs 108, which is not correct. It should instead be 96.

Where have I gone wrong in the code?

Comment: for even numbers you are just adding even numbers, test the input for whether they are odd or even and then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Why do you think this code adds *odd* numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the first number is even or odd first, because if it is even, it is going to sum the even numbers instead of odd ones since you are increasing "i" by 2 after every iteration. Try adding the line below **before the for loop**.

```
if(num1%2==0){num1++);
```

Comment: Just as note, patching `num2` is not necessary.

Comment: @Zabuza you're right, I was just about to update the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Your loop sums the even numbers if you start with an even number.

Check your code:

```
for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i += 2)
```

Assume `num1` is even, e.g. `4`. Then your loop starts with `i = 4`. And then you continue with `+= 2`, so you end up with `6, 8, 10, ...`, i.e. the even numbers.

---

### Solution

You can simply fix it by patching `num1` before your loop.

```
// Put this before your loop
if (num1 % 2 == 0) { // checks if num1 is even
    num1++;
}
```

This way you will start with `5` then, and then get `7, 9, 11, ...`.

Comment: I tried this, however I'm still not getting the correct output .. now for 3 and 11 I am getting 52

Comment: Then you did something wrong. It works on my end. Impossible to say what exactly without seeing what you did though.

Answer (score 2):

To [sum a range of numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50487):

> Take the average of the first number and the last number, and multiply by the number of numbers.

But, first you need to make sure you lower and upper bounds are odd numbers. This is actually what is the problem with the code in the question.

Once that is done, calculate the *average number*, and the *number of numbers*:

```
public static long sumOddNumbers(int min, int max) {
    long minOdd = (min % 2 == 1 ? min : min + 1); // Round up to odd number
    long maxOdd = (max % 2 == 1 ? max : max - 1); // Round down to odd number
    if (minOdd > maxOdd)
        return 0;

    // average = (minOdd + maxOdd) / 2
    // count = (maxOdd - minOdd) / 2 + 1
    // sum = count * average
    return ((maxOdd - minOdd) / 2 + 1) * (minOdd + maxOdd) / 2;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(sumOddNumbers(3, 11)); // prints: 35
System.out.println(sumOddNumbers(4, 20)); // prints: 96
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easily with a mathematical formula.  But based on your question I presume you want to use a loop so here goes.

An odd number has the low order bit set to 1.

If the number is already odd, resetting that bit has no effect so it is still odd.
But setting that bit for an even number makes it the next higher odd number.

So use the bitwise OR operator.

3 | 1 = 3
4 | 1 = 5

And do the following:

```java
      int start = 4;
      int end = 20;
      int sum = 0;

      for (int i = (start | 1); i <= end; i += 2) {
         sum += i;
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
```

If you want to use streams in Java 8+ you can do it this way.

```java
      int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).filter(i -> i & 1 == 1).sum();
```

And the formula I was talking about is the following, derived using simple series summation.

For ints, `start` and `end`

```java
      start |= 1; // ensure start is next odd number
      end = (end | 1) - 2;// ensure end is last odd - 2

      int sum = ((start + end) * ((end - start) / 2 + 1)) / 2;
```

Comment: If you're going to use bit-manipulation, stick with it, i.e. use `filter(i -> (i & 1) == 1)`

Comment: @andreas  That is what I usually do when checking for even or odd numbers.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

If the two numbers are natural numbers, you can apply the formula:

```
Sum of odd natural numbers from m to n = sum of natural odd numbers up to n - sum of natural odd numbers up to m
                                       = (n/2)^2 - (m/2)^2
                                       where n is an even number or the next even number in case it is an odd number
```

**In the program:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("#1: ");
        int num1 = Math.abs(s.nextInt());
        System.out.print("#2: ");
        int num2 = Math.abs(s.nextInt());       

        System.out.println("Sum of natural odd numbers from "+num1+" to "+num2+" = "+sumNaturalOddOfRange(num1,num2));

        num1 = 5;
        num2 = 15;
        System.out.println("Sum of natural odd numbers from "+num1+" to "+num2+" = "+sumNaturalOddOfRange(num1,num2));

        num1 = 5;
        num2 = 16;
        System.out.println("Sum of natural odd numbers from "+num1+" to "+num2+" = "+sumNaturalOddOfRange(num1,num2));

        num1 = 6;
        num2 = 15;
        System.out.println("Sum of natural odd numbers from "+num1+" to "+num2+" = "+sumNaturalOddOfRange(num1,num2));
    }
    static int sumNaturalOddOfRange(int num1, int num2) {
        if(num2%2==1)
            num2++;
        return (int)(Math.pow(num2 / 2, 2) - Math.pow(num1 / 2, 2));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
#1: 10
#2: 20
Sum of natural odd numbers from 10 to 20 = 75
Sum of natural odd numbers from 5 to 15 = 60
Sum of natural odd numbers from 5 to 16 = 60
Sum of natural odd numbers from 6 to 15 = 55
```

Comment: For the most part, I like it.  But if your number goes from odd to odd it doesn't work.  I think you should modify `num2` to be `num2 = num2 + 1`.  If you  agree fix it and I will definitely upvote it. You may want to do some tests to prove me right or wrong.  Also, imo, Math.pow is overkill for this I would just multiply each by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Here is the answer**     
       public static void main(String[] args) {         
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("#1: ");
            int num1 = s.nextInt();
            System.out.print("#2: ");
            int num2 = s.nextInt();
            int sum = 0;
            if (num1%2==0) {            
                num1++; 
            }

           for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {

                sum +=i;

    }


    System.out.print(sum);  
    }
```